# Getting Cobertura reports for pax-exam Integration Tests

Tags: osgi, integration-testing, cobertura

I am running my Integration Tests using maven and the failsafe plugin. The tests themselves are executed using pax-exam (which uses pax-runner). Failsafe runs at the integration-test phase, and Cobertura at verify.

While I get reports for all my junit tests, I get nothing from the Integration Tests.

Is this even technically feasible, or would pax-runner need to support cobertura directly?

Any idea how I could solve this? I am also open to any other plugin that helps, but I do need to run integration tests on OSGi bundles..

Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering why you need code coverage for your PAX Exam integration tests.  IMHO these should be reserved for verifying that e.g., the OSGi metadata is correct and less about the specific functionality, so a coverage report of that logic would not be measuring much useful.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for your comment. I currently have rather low coverage for a lot of the functionality of my code. I could write a ton of unit tests, but I'm not sure it'd really prove anything. The real functionality I want to test requires multiple bundles, so I have to test them together. Or do we have different concepts of what integration tests are for and about? thanks!

Comment: I think of using PAX Exam when I need to verify my bundles will work in the context of a real OSGi runtime.  Anything that depends on OSGi--Package-Imports and Package-Export, service or bundle events, interactions with the service registry, etc.--are fair to test.  However, I think most of the actual functionality could be tested outside an OSGi container, and this is where code coverage makes sense.  If this isn't the case, some refactorings with a keen eye to testability can help.  I've also found DS and Blueprint help as well since there are fewer (code) dependencies on the OSGi classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's been a while. The closest thing I've found that could help out is instrumenting the builds and collecting cobertura.ser files after the pax-exam tests have run. It is far from a simple setup. I'll report as I go! [relevant reference](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/instrumentingDeploymentArtifact.html)